Why is JS/CSS text rendered when setting display: inline globally?
When I do this from JSFiddle:
<p>Hi</p><p>Bye</p>

* {
  display: inline
}

I get this result.
Screenshot:

Text:
* { display: inline; } /* EOS */ :root { color-scheme: light; } const customConsole = (w) => { const pushToConsole = (payload, type) => { w.parent.postMessage({ console: { payload: stringify(payload), type: type } }, "*") } w.onerror = (message, url, line, column) => { // the line needs to correspond with the editor panel // unfortunately this number needs to be altered every time this view is changed line = line - 70 if (line < 0){ pushToConsole(message, "error") } else { pushToConsole(`[${line}:${column}] ${message}`, "error") } } let console = (function(systemConsole){ return { log: function(){ let args = Array.from(arguments) pushToConsole(args, "log") systemConsole.log.apply(this, args) }, info: function(){ let args = Array.from(arguments) pushToConsole(args, "info") systemConsole.info.apply(this, args) }, warn: function(){ let args = Array.from(arguments) pushToConsole(args, "warn") systemConsole.warn.apply(this, args) }, error: function(){ let args = Array.from(arguments) pushToConsole(args, "error") systemConsole.error.apply(this, args) }, system: function(arg){ pushToConsole(arg, "system") }, clear: function(){ systemConsole.clear.apply(this, {}) }, time: function(){ let args = Array.from(arguments) systemConsole.time.apply(this, args) }, assert: function(assertion, label){ if (!assertion){ pushToConsole(label, "log") } let args = Array.from(arguments) systemConsole.assert.apply(this, args) } } }(window.console)) window.console = { ...window.console, ...console } console.system("Running fiddle") } if (window.parent){ customConsole(window) } HiBye // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){ window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", { height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height, slug: "" }], "*") } // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually window.name = "result" const allLines = [] const cssElement = document.querySelector("#compiled-css") window.addEventListener("message", (message) => { if (message.data.console){ let insert = document.querySelector("#insert") allLines.push(message.data.console.payload) insert.innerHTML = allLines.join(";\r") let result = eval.call(null, message.data.console.payload) if (result !== undefined){ console.log(result) } } if (message.data.css){ cssElement.textContent = message.data.css.payload } if (message.data.html){ document.body.innerHTML = message.data.html.payload } })

Why is this happening?

because your html code is more than those p, Right click to inspect the code

I disagree with this being closed as a typo/not useful for future readers. Yes this is pretty "basic" and once you deal with selectors you can understand quite easily why this happens, but I remember pretty clearly that when I first realized that it was also some gotcha moment for me and I can perfectly understand how someone could want to have more clarification  on this behavior. Moreover since not all content behave like this (e.g. <template> content, or <canvas> content when scripting is enabled, and maybe others).

Your * includes all tags, including <style> and <script> that are present in that page. They are all inline so that's the consequence.

Oh that's interesting.

It is surprising. But if you try without it you can inspect that default for those tags is display: none

One notable special case here is the content of <template> tags, which do live in a shadow-DOM even though they're declared in the markup and are thus not targeted by the (light) * rule. Arguably, <script> and <style> contents could have been defined the same (if shadow DOM had been a thing at the time they were defined).

And an even better case, the contents of a <canvas> element when scripting is enabled. It does live in the DOM and is selectable by DOM methods (and by CSS), but can't get its display changed: https://jsfiddle.net/p9d51tqg/
